# Google map does not work any more

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have seen most of the posts about google map, but no one have answered my question considering new google Api changes in 2018.

I have this code in my page:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = { lat: 35.799064, lng: 51.441882 };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 16
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: myLatLng,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    }

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I verified my website with uploading a google file in the root of my website.

I have Created an Api key and got the key from google and pasted it in my page.

I tested my Api key in both: **Restricted to my website** and **no restriction**.

But still I have the error:

> Oops! Something went wrong

This the address of page: [Page With Google Map](http://calmclinic.ir/Contactus.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the browser console you will see the following error message:

`Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererDeniedMapError`

According to the documentation this error means:

> Your application **was blocked for non-compliance** with the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service, following several email notifications. To appeal the block and have your implementation reviewed, please complete this form. You will receive a response via email within a few business days.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-denied-map-error

You should reach out to the compliance team via [webform](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdndZBL6qgP4iDUx8M7i5_yyf1AVji5OEag8qERRJ6vyqK7Kw/viewform) in order to unblock your domain.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Obviously your answer is true and I did what you said and now I am waiting for the email.